# Bootstrap won't collapse

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

So, my navbar i copied from bootstrap doesn't close while it is like that., collapses but can't uncollapse, and I have checked my code many times and searched every question.
I have tried using other source of js and such, but i still don't get it.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<!--libraries -->
<script type=text/javascript src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- JS Code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
});
</script>

<title>BSMUN'17 </title>
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<!-- Header -->
<header style="margin: 0 auto" class="animated fadeIn">
<div class="header animated" align="middle">
    <img src="bsmun-logo.png" id="logo-header" class="logo animated fadeInUp" align="middle">
    <div class="header-text animated fadeInUp">
        <h1 class="animated fadeIn">BSMUN'17</h1>
        <h2 class="animated fadeIn">27-29 July</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="nav" id="nav1"></ul>
</header>
<!-- JS Scripts -->
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am a beginner you might say, so any details would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Could you try putting js files at the bottom instead of above the css?

Comment: Doesn't work, sorry.

Comment: If you can, upload a live demo so we can debug. Otherwise, let us see the dev console. Any errors present? What browser?

Comment: no error in dev console, although wes fosters solution solves, dropdown part, it doesn't solve the menu not closing, it only closes when i click on a link.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByKmMT4AAY7TQVBiNGtwcjhUdFU here is the file if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

Should be

```
// v---- Add the period
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

Notice the period in the jQuery selector denoting the `dropdown-toggle` classname

Comment: This solves the dropdown, but still can't close the navbar when it is in the mobile mode (note that If i click on a link, navbar closes)

Comment: This is because `data-toggle="dropdown"` on your element does the same thing as calling `$('dropdown-toggle').dropdown()` on the element. Use one or the other, not both.

Comment: doesn't work deleting one sorry, it even makes things worse. as collapsed navbar doesn't open.